# How can I use the J2EE Timer Service API in the Servlet startup code?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, timer, startup

For a background job which I would like to run in a J2EE container, I found the suggestion to create a startup servlet and use the Timer Service API to create a managed Timer (in the answers for [What tools are there for timed batch processes in J2EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78194/what-tools-are-there-for-timed-batch-processes-in-j2ee)).

To create a timer, I need a context which implements the timer API. ([Example](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Session5.html))

In the Servlet class, I override the init method, but it has only access to a ServletContext, but not to a SessionContext. A ServletContext does not have methods to create timers, so I am stuck here.

How can I access the J2EE timer service in the startup code of a servlet?

Comment: What do you think you need the timer for?  More details would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I hear timer job, I can't help but think that this should be separated from a Java EE app server.  You can use something like Quartz, or an operating system scheduled task, or a batch manager like AutoSys, but embedding it into a servlet seems like a misuse of servlets to me.

Java EE 5 containers have a TimerService that's an EJB.  Perhaps [this](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) will help you sort it out.

Comment: In the Sun example, the timer will be created in the business method of an enterprise bean. So I would need to write a client class for this stateless session bean, create an instance of this client in a startup servlet, and use it to call the timer creation method.

Comment: Yes.  It's reasonable to assume that you've already got a servlet of some kind in your Java EE web app.  Add the code into its init() method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Servlet startup code (which will be executed after every redeployment) I found it cleaner to start timers in the startup of the EJB. With EJB 3.1 and Singleton EJB this now is possible with much less code:

http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_startup_shutdown_callbacks